# Drawn image is not visible in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following code in pygame (irrelevant stuff removed):

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
resolution = 1360,768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((resolution),0,32)

font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 24)
black = 0,0,0
white = 255,255,255

x = 200
y = 200

while True:
    image = pygame.Surface([3,3],SRCALPHA)  # creates a surface to draw the protagonist on
    protagonist=pygame.draw.circle(image, white, (x,y), 3, 3) # draws the protagonist on the surface image
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if keystate[K_ESCAPE]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    screen.fill(black)
    text = font.render("This text appears on the screen", 1, (white))
    screen.blit(text, (100, 100)) 
    screen.blit(image,(x, y)) # This does not appear on the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

The text appears on the screen as intended, but not the image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface you draw the circle on:

```
image = pygame.Surface([3,3],SRCALPHA)
```

is only 3x3 pixels in size.

Then you draw the circle:

```
pygame.draw.circle(image, white, (x,y), 3, 3)
```

at position `x, y`, but `x, y` is actually `200, 200`, so you draw it way outside the visible area of the `image` surface.

---

You can skip creating the `image` surface altogether and draw directly to the `screen` surface:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if keystate[K_ESCAPE]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.circle(image, white, (x,y), 3, 3)
    text = font.render("This text appears on the screen", 1, (white))
    screen.blit(text, (100, 100)) 
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also, you don't need to call `pygame.display.flip()` *and* `pygame.display.update()`

Comment: I'm drawing directly on the screen using `pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x,y), 3, 3)` as you advised and it's working perfectly! Thank you for the extra advice as well!

Answer (score 0):

`Surface` instances are black in color by default, so you must `fill` to see it in a black background:

```
image.fill((255, 255, 255)) # fill the image Surface to white instead of default black
```